# Is Warning Sign in Unity Console Effect The Game ? Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am in creating the game with unity using C#.

So far i have done it much. But sometimes i assign a variable but never used it.
So in console unity they warn me for that with sign warning. The warning sign is like :

```
**Assets/script/merchant/rogerShop/RogerSellScript.cs(20,22): warning CS0414: The private field `RogerSellScript.mm' is assigned but its value is never used**
```

I have this total 500 total warning. But the game run normally.

My question is, is the warning effect the game ? Or with could just ignore it.
How it is effect the game ? What if i don't solve it ?

Thanks

Dennis

Comment: What is the purpose of creating a field, assigning a value, and never using it?

Comment: Beyond load the memory of a bunch of variable that you will not use, it is considered a bad programming practice and if you plan to run the app on a mobile device between less loads of unnecessary things the memory is better

Comment: sometimes i just creating a variable and realize it never used when i change the logic. but i do not delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a performance warning, saying that you've allocated a variable and stored a value in it but never used that value. This wastes both memory and CPU, but doesn't "break" anything, unless it indicates a logic problem (e.g. you *meant* to use the value in some calculation, but you forgot).

Comment: yes.. so i must make a correction for better perfomance. thanks